# How to make sparse image file from original firmware?

Tags: rom-flashing

I accidently erased `/system` partition and now have my Gionee S10C phone bricked.

I downloaded original firmware, but I can see series of system image files.(This firmware is to be used by Qualcomm Flash Image Loader)

```
system_1.img, system_2.img, ..., system_53.img
```

When I'm trying to install the original firmware using QFIL by putting the phone in EDL mode, I get `sahara fail error`. (Same error in [here](https://blog.hovatek.com/how-to-fix-sahara-fail-error-in-qfil/#:%7E:text=Causes%20of%20QFIL%20Sahara%20fail%20and%20solutions&text=Using%20an%20old%20QFIL%20version,QFIL%20relative%20to%20your%20device.&text=If%20you%27re%20encountering%20Sahara,QFIL%20that%20comes%20with%20it.) and I tried most of the fixes I can find, but nothing works)

Now, is there any way to use the above 53 system images to restore my phone using `fastboot flash` command?

I'm sure only `system` partition is needed to be restored to get my phone working again, because I haven't modified any other partitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

concatenate files with dd seek=$offset from xml and then sparse with img2simg

`rawprogram0.xml` contains

```
- partition name:    filename="system.img"
- partition size:    num_partition_sectors="8388608"
- partition offset:  start_sector="1312768"
```

`rawprogram_unsparse.xml` contains system_1.img - system_53.img

```
- file name:         filename="system_1.img"
- file size:         num_partition_sectors="262160"
- file offset:       start_sector="1312768"
```

Note: we don't want the offset so we will subtract from `start_sector`

1312768 - 1312768 = 0

```
- file name:         filename="system_1.img"
- file size:         num_partition_sectors="262160"
- file offset:       start_sector="0"
```

1576968 - 1312768 = 264200

```
- file name:         filename="system_2.img"
- file size:         num_partition_sectors="16"
- file offset:       start_sector="264200"
```

1581024 - 1312768 = 268256

```
- file name:         filename="system_3.img"
- file size:         num_partition_sectors="256048"
- file offset:       start_sector="268256"
```

Now use the **dd** `seek` parameter to paste junks into proper offsets
(sparse is filled with zeros)

`bs=$SECTOR_SIZE_IN_BYTES`
`seek=$start_sector`
`count=$num_partition_sectors`

```
dd if=system_1.img count=262160 seek=0       bs=512 of=system_ext4.img
dd if=system_2.img count=16     seek=264200  bs=512 of=system_ext4.img
dd if=system_3.img count=256048 seek=268256  bs=512 of=system_ext4.img
...
dd if=/dev/zero    count=0      seek=8388608 bs=512 of=system_ext4.img
```

the result is mountable ext4 partition image

```
mkdir system
sudo mount -t ext4 -o loop system_ext4.img system
ls system
```

finally this file can be sparsed with `img2simg`

```
sudo apt install -y f2fs-tools android-tools-fsutils android-sdk-platform-tools-common
img2simg system_ext4.img system.img
```

---

**GNU bash script with sed**

```
#/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob

bs=512
label=system
input=rawprogram0.xml
output=rawprogram_unsparse.xml

source <(sed -nr "s,.*\s(filename=.${label}\.img.)\s.*\s(num_partition_sectors=.[0-9]+.)\s.*\s(start_sector=.[0-9]+.).*,\1; \2; \3;,p" "$input" | head -n1)

out=$filename
off=${start_sector:-0}
end=${num_partition_sectors:-0}

printf '%s\n' "${label}"_+([0-9]).img | cut -d. -f1 | sort -t_ -k2n | xargs -n1 -I_ echo _.img | \
while read -r file
  do
    source <(sed -nr "s,.*\s(filename=.${file}.)\s.*\s(num_partition_sectors=.[0-9]+.)\s.*\s(start_sector=.[0-9]+.).*,\1; \2; \3;,p" "$output" | head -n1)
    dd if="$filename" of="$out" bs=${bs:-512} count=${num_partition_sectors:-0} seek=$((start_sector-off)) status=none || exit 1
    echo "filename=$filename num_partition_sectors=$num_partition_sectors start_sector=$((start_sector-off))"
done

dd if=/dev/zero of="$out" bs=${bs:-512} count=0 seek=$end status=none || exit 1
echo "filename=$out num_partition_sectors=$end start_sector=$off"

file "$out"
e2fsck -n "$out" | grep clean || exit 1
mv "$out" "${out%.*}.raw"
img2simg "${out%.*}.raw" "$out" || exit 1
file "$out"
echo "Done."

exit 0
```